# Visual Basic tools (UML to Code or Reverse Engineering)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb6, uml, reverse-engineering

I would like to either generate VB Code from UML or vice versa UML from Code.

Does anyone know some UML tools for VB6 or VB.Net that can do this?
Is it possible with Visual Studio 2010?

best regards

Comment: See also the question about [automatically generating UML diagrams from a VB6 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191287/visual-basic-project-code-to-uml-diagram-tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse engineering can be done using the [Visualisation and Modelling Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff655021.aspx) for Visual Studios 2010 Ultimate.